# How to make code chunk output scrollable horizontally in quarto revealjs presentation

Tags: css, r, rstudio, quarto

I made a presentation with a scrollable code chunk output using the xaringan package in R before like the photo shown below.

I want to make the same scrollable code chunk output in quarto revealjs presentation. Anyone knows how to do it in quarto presentation?

scrollable code chunk output:
[image]

If it helps, here is the css code I used before when making a presentation in xaringan.

Thank you in advance!

```
/* scrollable code chunk output */
.remark-code {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: .5em;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(131, 139, 139);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need two steps to do the same in Quarto revealjs. At first, define a css class with `overflow-x: auto` and then pass the class to the chunk option `class-output` so that output of that will have horizontal scrolling.

````
---
title: Output Horizontal scrolling
format: revealjs
engine: knitr
---

## Quarto

```{r}
#| class-output: hscroll

library(gapminder)
df <- dplyr::bind_cols(gapminder, gapminder, .name_repair = "minimal")

head(df)
```

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.hscroll {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```
````

---

[image: horizontal scrolling in output in revealjs]

---

And if you want to do this for code chunks, instead of passing the `.hscroll` class as a chunk option to a specific chunk, use the knitr `opts_chunk` key in the yaml section.

````
---
title: Output Horizontal scrolling
format: revealjs
engine: knitr
knitr:
  opts_chunk: 
    class-output: hscroll
---

## Quarto

```{r}
library(gapminder)
df <- dplyr::bind_cols(gapminder, gapminder, .name_repair = "minimal")

head(df)
```

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.hscroll {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```
````

Comment: Thank you so much, @shafee. 
The horizontal scrolling works. Highly appreciated.

I tried to add a color and background option to the code like the one below but it does not work. Any possible reason why? Thanks, again!

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.hscroll {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(131, 139, 139);
}
```

Comment: The reason its not working because the hscroll class is added for `pre` tag, but the code tag is using `#fff` as bg color. so `hscroll` can not override that. So in this case ideal option would be using sass variable.

Comment: Can you post a new question regarding this? I think a separate question and answer regarding code background would be more useful on this site : ).