# How do I change the Body Width of the content box of a slide in Quarto

Tags: r, quarto, skimr

This is driving me crazy. It's just a basic example. This is the Quarto code.

````
```{r}
#| echo: true
library(tidyverse)
library(skimr)
```

```{r}
#| echo: true
skim(diamonds)
```
````

The output I get is:

[image]

The question is: How do I extend the width of the content box to avoid the wrapping? I have tried everything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have several options. Firstly, see the [presentation size](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#presentation-size) section from quarto docs. Secondly check the [Content Overflow](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/index.html#content-overflow) to reduce the output font size. And another thing you can try is to make the output horizontally scrollable. For that check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75471871/10858321)

Comment: And I would also recommend posting reproducible and complete example. :)

Comment: Could you please share your yaml? Is this a revealjs presentation?