# Use Hmisc::describe() in RevealJS/Quarto without creating line breaks

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

The following code

````
---
title: "Test"
format: revealjs
---

```{r}
library(Hmisc)
describe(mtcars)
```
````

will create a description of all variables in the `mtcars` dataset. Since it's too wide to fit on the page, there are line breaks after the 10-percentile. What are my options if I don't want line breaks? Can I scale the output chunk by some factor? Another option would be to allow for a horizontal slider, but I tried following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75471871/1436812) but it didn't fix the issue. I guess this means that the line breaks aren't introduced by Quarto but by the `describe()` function.

Comment: Would a different package also be an option? E.g. `modelsummary::datasummary_skim(mtcars)` produces better HTML output for revealjs compared to `describe`.

Comment: @Julian: I was actually looking for something that produced a non-HTML output, but maybe I should just give up on that part. Let's say I wanted to use `datasummary_skim`, how would I make it fit horizontally?

Comment: @Julian: So this shouldn't be happening: https://imgbox.com/YnghmSyF ?

Comment: You are using the plain text output mode of `describe`.  Try two different `html` options: `options(prType='html'); describe(mydata); print(describe(mydata), 'continuous'))`

Comment: Thanks @FrankHarrell! The one with sparklines look really neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an `datasummary_skim` option:

````
---
title: "Test"
format: revealjs
---

<style>
.cell-output-display:not(.no-overflow-x) {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
  
</style>


```{r}
modelsummary::datasummary_skim(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Weird. I don't get a scrollbar with this code. The max column is cropped here. Which Quarto version are you on?

Comment: Ah nevermind, the scrollbar was below the slide because the table height was too large. This works. Thanks.